# Audi S4 (B6) - Misc leaks in engine

Tags: engine, leak, audi, oil-leak, s4

Got a 05 audi s4 with about 200k miles.

Got a basic inspection done and was told that the engine has misc leaks without any further explanation.

(Further inspection required more costs, didn't want to worry about it then)

My understanding is that the engine has many parts where leaks can come from, so unless someone looks at it or uses that leak color fluid to see where the leaks are coming from, it's tough to diagnose without an in depth look.

**Question**

Is there an all-purpose engine leak stopper formula that encompasses most/all of the engine?

And this is something you can pour directly into the engine, not the gas tank or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, there isn't any leak stopper formula that will stop all the possible leaks. Your car is oozing, which is very normal after 200k miles!

The longer answer is that the leaks could be coming from many systems:

- Engine seals
- Transmission/gearbox seals
- Power steering unit
- Cooling system

Leaks can come from seals, loose or degraded hoses. It can be hard to see the source of a leak because the fluids spread out over a wide area and get mixed with road grime. You also may have more than one leak. Sometimes if you want to know the source of the leak(s) you have to get the engine cleaned.

There are stop-leak products for each system, but the advice from previous questions on this site is not to use them as they can do more harm than good, or just don't work. Keep an eye on your fluid levels, if they are slow leaks that don't require frequent refilling then my advice would be to leave it alone. If the leaks are enough you have to frequently refill a fluid or you really want to keep the car long-term I would ask a mechanic to look into replacing the seal or hose that is the culprit.

Comment: appreciate it. if im not a mechanic, have no knowledge of cars, could a small step be to just replace any/all small seals/hoses just for the sake of replacing it with something brand new and see if that fixes it?

Comment: It it ain't broke or likely to don't fix it @and1. High mileage cars can be a bit of a rabbit hole, once you start taking one apart you never know where you'll be able to stop. Plus, you could end up replacing all sorts of perfectly good parts without fixing the actual problem.